# Elegant way to stop a running process in Sublime Text 3, without closing all of Sublime?

Tags: process, sublime-text-3

I just started learning C++, and discovered that [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667502/what-does-permission-denied-id-returned-1-exit-status-mean), where code ran prior fails to close preventing it to run again, can force you to end the process before continuing.

This can be solved by opening and closing Sublime, but it feels dirty; is there a way to end the specific process without closing all of Sublime? For REPL and Python, I could just right-click the output field and kill it there, for reference.

Comment: What about "Tools->Cancel Build" ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531742/7501765

Comment: That is greyed out, I guess since the code has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have the terminal console (located at the lower part of of sublime console) open, then right click and go to the language you are running and select cancel build.
( I tested this in Linux Mint but it should work in windows and Mac too)

[image]